# Need help in writing sql xquery

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery-sql

I need to select specific values from xml in sql using xquery. Given below is the xml

```
DECLARE @v_productss_xml XML

set @v_productss_xml = 

'<Products EventTemplateId="1">
  <Product ProductId="BD0A7272-5D6D-47DA-9781-1BE4ACAC2D34" ProductName="Income Tax5">
    <Field FieldId="1" Fieldname="f1" />
    <Field FieldId="" Fieldname="f5" />
    <Field FieldId="" Fieldname="f6" />
  </Product>
  <Product ProductId="2EEB192E-1E95-4E6F-8A05-248DFC3A37EE" ProductName="Income Tax6">
    <Field FieldId="4" Fieldname="e1" />
    <Field FieldId="" Fieldname="e4" />
  </Product>
</Products>'
```

I want the ProductId, Fieldname for rows when FieldId="". For the xml above that would be

```
BD0A7272-5D6D-47DA-9781-1BE4ACAC2D34, f5
BD0A7272-5D6D-47DA-9781-1BE4ACAC2D34, f6
2EEB192E-1E95-4E6F-8A05-248DFC3A37EE, e4
```

I am able to compare the fieldid attribute but able to select the product id.
Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are after this:

```
SELECT
    Nodes.node.value('@ProductId', 'varchar(50)') AS ProductId,
    Nodes.node.value('(Field[@FieldId=""]/@Fieldname)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS Field
FROM
    @v_productss_xml.nodes('//Product') AS Nodes(node);
```

Basically, find the `//Product` nodes in the xml document, then, for each row, evaluate the `@ProductId` attribute, and then, on the Field which has an empty `FieldId` attribute, evaluate the `@Fieldname` attribute.

*Re : Updated requirement / new Xml*

> The query given by you is returning only the first child record, I need all the child records with empty value. Thank you for your help

If there is more than one child, then I would change the subject to the `Field`, do the filtering on the `empty` attribute immediately, and then navigate back to the parent to obtain the `ProductId`. Like so:

```
SELECT
    Nodes.node.value('parent::Product/@ProductId', 'varchar(50)') AS ProductId,
    Nodes.node.value('@Fieldname', 'varchar(50)') AS attrib
FROM
    @v_productss_xml.nodes('//Product/Field[@FieldId=""]') AS Nodes(node);
```

Comment: Hi, The query given by you is returning only the first child record, I need all the child records with empty value. Thank you for your help